# Center any image in a static position

Tags: html, css, center, centering

Well, I wasn't able to find any satisfactory answer to my question, so I try to post it.

I need to click on any image on my web site and display it at full size in a static viewport with opaque background.

My actual code is this:

```
= link_to hide_image_path, :remote => :true, :title => "Close" do
  .full_screen_image
  .opaque
    %img.image-middle{:src => UrlSafeBase64.decode64(image), :alt => ""}
```

With the following .CSS

/* this fragment will provide a static semi-transparent grey layer, and it runs correctly */

```
.full_screen_image {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #6c6c6c;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

/* this should provide a 100% opaque layer on top of the previous one

```
.opaque {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2005;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

/* the last one is the image

```
.image-middle {
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Well, 
 - the image is 100 opaque, and this is correct, BUT
 - it is positioned all around and not in the center of the screen as described by the .image-middle rule
 - the first layer doesn't scroll (this is the expected behavior)
 - the image scroll (this is NOT the expected behavior)

I need to achieve the expected results only using CSS/HTML, with no Jquery/Jscript

Comment: Could we have a working link or images, please? It's hard to understand what you mean by "positioned all around".

Comment: you have set **position:static** => that would scroll with scrollbar; and  what does it mean by positioned all around ? Are the images repeating?

Comment: You can see my solution below, but static was an error.

This is not important now, but with 'images all around' i intended each image, one at a time, didn't respect the positioning in the .image-middle CSS, but display randomly:
overflowing sometimes on the right, sometimes on the left. They also position below the bottom part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by this using jquery .

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
                    type: 'inline',
                    fixedContentPos: false,
                    fixedBgPos: true,
                    overflowY: 'auto',
                    closeBtnInside: true,
                    preloader: false,
                    midClick: true,
                    removalDelay: 300,
                    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Add this to you HTML code it will show a picture and by clicking on picture it will show you the full size image

```
<div class="mfp-hide">
            <div id="small-dialog1" class="pop_up">
                <h2>work1</h2>
                <img src="yourpic.JPG" alt="images "/>


        <div class="gallerylist-wrapper">               
                <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog1">
                    <img src="yourpic.JPG" height="200px" width="200px"  alt="Image 1"/>
                    <span><img src="yourpic.JPG" alt="image "/> </span>
                    <div class="desc">

                    </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Brendom, thank for your answer, but it is not good, as a requirement was to use only CSS and no JQuery/JScript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **KISS** is my answer!

The correct code is the following

```
= link_to hide_image_path, :remote => :true, :title => "Close" do
  .full_screen_image
  %img.image-middle{:src => UrlSafeBase64.decode64(image), :alt => ""}
```

with the following 2 CSS rules (Note it is fixed and not static!):

```
.full_screen_image {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #6c6c6c;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
}

.image-middle {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2005;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Thanks for the help, and I hope this solution can help others with a similar problem/question.